# If a element hasClass then display:none;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the hasClass javascript element to see if it should make a div display none or keep it displayed as normal.

Here is the code snippet of what I currently have

```
   if (!$('cool').hasClass('hot')) {
   }
```

I want it to display none if it has class hot. What code would I use to do this?

EDIT: Alright so I have read the comments. I am not exactly sure how hasClass works but from what I have gathered it uses a html tag so it checks if it has a html tag.

I just want it to check if a div has the class "hot" that is will not appear.

Comment: `$('cool')` is looking for `<cool`... What is your HTML?

Comment: You know you could do this with CSS alone? `.hot { display: none; }`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to display none"?

Comment: *"it uses a html tag so it checks if it has a html tag"* I think you are confusing something here. `.hasClass` accepts a *class name* which is just a string. However, you have to select elements you want to test for the class *first*. And for this selection you can use any selector that jQuery supports. `cool` is a valid selector, but since there is no HTML element with that tag name, it won't select anything. I think you would benefit the most by going through the [**jQuery tutorial**](http://learn.jquery.com/) thoroughly, instead of "patching" your knowledge.

Comment: "it uses a html tag so it checks if it has a html tag" — No, it checks that is a member of a class. "a div has the class "hot"" — If you want to match a div then why are you saying `cool`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use the `:not()` selector based on the OP's original premise -

(*I'm assuming that 'cool' and 'hot' are classes in this example*)

```
$('.cool:not(.hot)').css({'display':'none'});
```

You could also use the `.not()` method -

```
$('.cool').not('.hot').css({'display':'none'});
```

Answer (score 5):

Forget the `if` statement, just select only elements that match your condition in the first place.

```
jQuery('cool.hot').addClass('foo'); // Where .foo { display: none; }
```

NB: There is no `<cool>` element in HTML.

Comment: Gotta love jQuery's use of set theory. Alternately, of course: `$('cool.hot').hide();`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Shouldn't forget the `<blink>`, `<hot>` will suit more for that... :D